# CMake only accepting `find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)` in add_subdirectory, not in root project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

**Context**

Using the below `CMakeLists.txt`, it build the `Qt` test project without issues ONLY when included to a parent project like:

```
RootProject
  +--CMakeLists.txt      // Parent CMake
  +--TestQt
       +--testwidget.cpp 
       +--testwidget.hpp // Empty class, just extends QWidget
       +--CMakeLists.txt // My Test Project CMake
```

Parent Project just contain:

```
add_subdirectory( "TestQt" )
```

As soon as I try to build the "TestQt" project standalone, it just return an error like:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):   By not providing
>   "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project   has asked
>   CMake to find a package configuration file provided by   "Qt5Widgets",
>   but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake /
>   qt5widgets-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has   been installed.

`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is empty in both cases.

Currently using Debian with a slightly old CMAKE 3.0.2

**Question**

What is wrong/ missing?

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")


# Project name
project ( "TestQt" )
add_executable( UnitTest_TestQt UnitTest.cpp testwidget.cpp)
target_link_libraries(UnitTest_TestQt Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: Do a search to find where FindQt5Widgets.cmake is installed, and look to see what are  the contents of environment variables `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `Qt5Widgets_DIR`

Comment: Good catch with Qt5Widgets_DIR: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Widgets` when in subproject, but `Qt5Widgets_DIR-NOTFOUND` in standalone. Do you know why is not set in standalone?

Comment: I am investigating this issue, seem very weird.

Comment: That's confusing: you shouldn't have a `project ( "TestQt" )` inside another project.

Comment: @Velkan: Each project tries to be as independent as possible. Why is this project naming a problem?

Comment: As far as I know, 'there can be only one' project. And it must be in the root `CMakeLists.txt`. If it's not there, it will be added implicitly. Stuff breaks if you call `project()` in other `CMakeLists.txt` somewhere down the directory hierarchy.

Comment: I guess there is more in CMakeLlists.txt that you are showing here. The error says that it happens in line 16, but in your CMakeLists.txt, it is on line 6. Try with this small file and look to see if the error continues to happen

Comment: Ok, thanks Velkan. @Amadeux: Just because I simplified even more the CMakeLists.txt after to copy the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_package` needs `project` to work properly. Move the line `project("TestQt")` to the top of the file, right after `cmake_minimum_required`.